# Where to report Windows 10 Mobile bugs?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-520, developer-preview

I am using Windows 10 Mobile on Lumia 520 using Preview for Developers app in India. However, there are bugs in the system which I want to report. I don't know where to report them. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to "*Windows Feedback*" app.
- Click on "**+**" at the bottom.
- Post your feedback. MS might be going through every feedback, or
- Just click "**Filter**" at bottom, and search for similar problems and upvote them.

Please make sure to mark your feedback as problem if you are reporting a bug.

Comment: This answer appears to be for an *extremely* outdated Insider build? The correct app has been called `Feedback Hub` for months now, and has a different UI; the steps described here may as well be "find the feedback app and figure out how to use it."

Comment: lumia 520 only supports threshold build(latest being 10686.494), this is the way it is in 520, i know it because am using one

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the `Feedback Hub` app.
2. From the "hamburger" menu in the upper left, choose `Feedback`
3. Search for existing reports to upvote and/or comment on.
4. If you want to add a new feedback item, hit the `[+]` button in the upper right.

   - Mark the feedback as a "Problem" since it's a bug.
   - If there's more than one issue, send multiple pieces of feedback (one for each).
   - Make sure you provide a concise and descriptive title ("Bug report" is bad, "Excessive data sense warnings" would be good).
   - Specify the category as well as you can.